# JS Array.filter with Dynamic Filter Criterion

Tags: javascript

How can I dynamically declare a set of filters criteria without having to specify the number of filters?

For example, if I have a set of data, like this:

```
var data = [ 
  { item: { type: 'wood', size: 10 } }, 
  { item: { type: 'wood', size: 8 } },
  { item: { type: 'metal', size: 8 } } 
]
```

I Know that I can use JS `.filter()` to get all of the items that have `type` `wood` and `size` `8`:

```
function filterItems() {
  return data.filter(function(val) {
    return val['item'].type == 'wood' && 
           val['item'].size == 8;
  }
}
```

But what if I want to filter the items with an unknown number of filters, and have `.filter()` return all `data` items that match those criterion?

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/oXEZZL?editors=101) that reflects the above code.

Comment: how would these dynamic filter criteria be passed to your code?

Comment: I have a service Javascript file that accepts dynamic inputs  and then returns the filtered data based on the input criterion. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: i would write a simple comparator function and then chain my criteria in a series of filters, ex: `r.filter(comp, ["type","wood"]).filter(comp, ["size",8);`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could pass an array of conditions to the `filterItems()` function. Try this:

```
function filterItems(filters) {
  return data.filter(function(val) {
    for(var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++)
      if(val['item'][filters[i][0]] != filters[i][1])
        return false;
    return true;
  }
}
filterItems([['type', 'wood'], ['size', 8], ['someother', 'value']]);
```

The same idea can be applied in various formats, such as using objects instead of an array for increased readability.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to show me, can you clean up your code, please?

Comment: What cleanup are you looking for?

Comment: Soo.. it's fine? or not? I don't understand (And if not, please be specific, what don't you "like"?)

Comment: This is good and helpful. Just out of curiosity, is it possible to put the `for` loop outside of the `data.filter`?

Comment: No. You need to test any `val` against all conditions. You need that inside the filter function.

Comment: This answers my question. Is this a good way to filter for an input range, like `size >= 5`? Is there a way to do this without having to include an additional `if` statement in `filterItems()`?

Comment: If you need more elaborate conditions, either introduce this logic through a (much) more complicated inner if (probably with more values in the array), or revert to the method in major-mann's answer and use functions as conditions. Considering your comments regarding where the conditions are coming from, it seems the complication will be the same in both methods.

Comment: Doesn't this act more like "OR" than an "AND". Ex: if [['type', 'wood'], ['size', 8]] is true but [['someother', 'value']] returns false, it still returns the first two. What is one absolutely need to return what is filtered, and if not, return false? Like I need to return all three combinations or return nothing?

Answer (score 4):

I just did some one line refactor on Amit's answer for any data structure and nested properties support

```
// the function
filterItems = (data, filters) => data.filter(item => !filters.find(x => x.key.split('.').reduce((keys, key) => keys[key], item) !== x.value))

// how to use it
filterItems(data, [{ key: 'type', value: 'wood' }, { key: 'some.nested.prop', value: 'value' }])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isSingle(filter) {
    return (filter && 'o' in filter && 'm' in filter && 'v' in filter);
}

function isComposite(filter) {
    return (filter && 'lo' in filter);
}

function createBody(filter) {

    if (isComposite(filter)) {
        var bdy = "";
        if (filter.v.length > 1) {
            var o = filter.lo;
            return "(" + createBody(filter.v.shift()) + " " + o + " " + createBody({ lo: filter.lo, v: filter.v }) + ")";
        } else if (filter.v.length == 1) {
            return createBody(filter.v.shift());
        }
        return bdy;
    } else if (isSingle(filter)) {
        var o = filter.o;
        if (typeof filter.v == "string") filter.v = "'" + filter.v + "'"
        return "item." + filter.m + " " + o + "  " + filter.v;
    }
}
var createFunc = function (filter) {

    var body = createBody(filter);
    var f = new Function("item", " return " + body + ";");
    return f;
}

function applyFilter(input, filter) {
    if (filter == undefined) {
        return input;
    }

    var fun = createFunc(filter);
    var output = input.filter(fun);
    return output;
};
//m:member,o:operator,v:value.

var filterQuery1 = { m: "item.type", o: "==", v: "metal" };//simpe query
var filterQuery2 = { m: "item.size", o: ">", v: 8 };
var filterQuery3 = {
    lo: "&&", v: [
        { m: "item.type", o: "==", v: "metal" },
        { m: "item.size", o: "<", v: 9 }]
}; //composite query
var data = [
  { item: { type: 'wood', size: 10 } },
  { item: { type: 'wood', size: 8 } },
  { item: { type: 'metal', size: 8 } }
]
var result = applyFilter(data, filterQuery1);// or filterQuery2,filterQuery3

console.log(result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kd0kL098/

Comment: Please summarize your answer in words

Answer (score 1):

Amit's answer is great, but I wanted to add to it. In my case, I needed to return all parameters, else return none/false. Here is the edited code from Amit's

```
function filterItems(filters) {
  return data.filter(function(val) {
    let result = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++)
      if(val['item'][filters[i][0]] != filters[i][1])
        result = false;
    return result;
  }
}
filterItems([['type', 'wood'], ['size', 8], ['someother', 'value']]);
```