# JS Array.filter with Dynamic filter keys and data type

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I need to filter an objects in an array using dynamic keys.

already found a good related answer here:
[JS Array.filter with Dynamic Filter Criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170630/js-array-filter-with-dynamic-filter-criterion)

But mine is a bit more complex, essentially need to:

- filter values that includes the string criteria
- filter values from an integer

So far here is what I came up with:

Sample data to filter

```
const options = [
  {'id': 1, 'name': 'Blend', 'category_id': 1},
  {'id': 2, 'name': 'Blend', 'category_id': 2},
  {'id': 3, 'name': 'Condiment Feeding', 'category_id': 1},
  {'id': 4, 'name': 'Tenderize', 'category_id': 1},
];
```

Notice I have objects with similar name but different category_id and some of the names have more than one word.

My current code

```
let query = [], search = '';
let optionalFilter = '';
let optionalFilterValue = 0;

// Removes objects in the options array that is not equal to query value and returns remaining object
filterItems = (data, filters) => data.filter(item => !filters.find(x => x.key.split('.').reduce((keys, key) => keys[key], item).toString().toLowerCase() !== x.value.toString().toLowerCase()));

// Push query parameters if present
search != '' ? query.push({key: 'name', value: search}) : '';
optionalFilter != '' && optionalFilterValue != 0 ? query.push({key: optionalFilter, value: optionalFilterValue}) : '';

return filterItems(options, query);
```

Code is working but if I search for `'ble'` nothing would be returned since my code only looks for exact same value from criteria.

I tried using .includes()

```
filterItems = (data, filters) => data.filter(item => !filters.find(x => x.key.split('.').reduce((keys, key) => keys[key], item).toString().toLowerCase().includes(x.value.toString().toLowerCase())));
```

When searching for `'ble'` this will now return the object with name of `'Blend'` but if I add `category_id of 1` it also returns `Condiment Feeding and Tenderize` as they also have `category_id of 1` and `Blend with category_id of 2` since it matches `'ble'` using includes() method.

This might be a lot to ask but I hope someone could put me in the right direction.